# How to assert if a radio button is selected through Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriver

In Selenium I'm using pseudo selectors to select this radio button input (screen shot below). Then I'm trying to use `assertTrue` and the method `isSelected` to see if that radio button is selected. But I get an error.. see below:

```
import unittest
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_radio_button(self):
        filter_panel = self.browser.find_element_by_class_name('panel-filters')
        radio_button = filter_panel.find_element_by_css_selector('section.section-units > fieldset#filter-units > div.form-group:nth-child(2) > input')

        self.assertTrue(radio_button.isSelected());
```

I get this error when running my Selenium test:

**self.assertTrue(filter_units.isSelected());
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'isSelected'**

How can I test if this radio button is selected?

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you are using *Selenium Python* client through *unittest* module the relevant method is **`is_selected()`** but not `isSelected()`.

---

### is_selected()

[`is_selected()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.is_selected) is defined as:

```
is_selected()

Returns whether the element is selected.
Can be used to check if a checkbox or radio button is selected.
```

To *assert* if the *radio button* is *selected* or not and you can use either the following solution:

```
radio_button = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input.form-control#metric_0[name='filter_units'][value='MV']")
self.assertTrue(radio_button.is_selected()));
```